# Objects return null after presentModalViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, null

After showing a camera, my objects return null:

Here's how I show my UIImagePickerController (I initialize it before):

```
[self presentModalViewController:pickerOne animated:NO];
```

I add a object in my scrollView like this,

```
UIImageView *overlay = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"black_overlay.png"]];
[overlay setFrame:CGRectMake(((columnCount-1)*100)+((columnCount-1)*5)+5 ,((rowCount-1)*100)+((rowCount-1)*5)+11, 100, 100)];
[overlay.layer setCornerRadius:8.0];
[overlay.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[overlay setTag:12];
[theImageViewer addSubview:overlay];
```

And access it like this (after the camera has been closed):

```
UIImageView *overlayImage = (UIImageView*)[theImageViewer viewWithTag:[[arrayOverlays objectAtIndex:[arrayIds indexOfObject:imageThumbnail]] intValue]];
NSLog(@"OverlayImage: %@",[arrayOverlays objectAtIndex:[arrayIds indexOfObject:imageThumbnail]]);
```

And I get: `Real overlayImage, (null)`

Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was calling a action from a different class right after I dismissed the view. I simply made it a NSNotification and works fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. The `pickerOne` must be a property inside your current ViewController.
2. Your current ViewController must conform to protocol of `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`.
3. In the `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` implementation from the delegate you'll get the image object and dismiss the `modalViewController`.

That should do the trick.

Edit: just found a tutorial that explains this in detail:

http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/28/using-a-uiimagepickercontroller/

Note:`imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo` is deprecated in **iOS 3.0**

Comment: have you set the delegate of your pickerView to self?

Comment: yes, i have. I did everything you suggested. Even all my IBOutlets are now null, now.

Comment: are they connected properly? I don't know what your project looks like so I cannot help you there, but you should probably create a sample project and follow that tutorial. just to get the grasp of how the UIImagePicker works.

Comment: Well, yes. I have added a property for all my IBOutlets as well as sythesizing the. If this helps, in my imagePickerDidFinishPickingImage, I present another modalViewController, then close it and there is where my objects are returning null. I have used UIImagePicker numerous times without any problems.